# Problem in InAppBilling in HTC Hero

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working in an app that has inAppPurchasing. I had implement it, but yesterday it stopped, Now I can't able to open in app Page. I have not developer account. Is this the Problem or is it device problem, I m struggling with it for two days Please help me.

```
boolean bindResult = bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.MarketBillingService.BIND"), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            if(bindResult){
                Log.i(TAG,"Market Billing Service Successfully Bound");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Market Billing Service could not be bound.");
                //TODO stop user continuing
            }
```

in console "Market Billing Service could not be bound" prints.

Comment: are installing the signed .apk in your device that you have uploaded in Android Market ?

Comment: no, i have not uploaded in android market.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the Android Market's old version. In-App Billing requires Market version 2.3.4 or higher, please check your device's Market version and update it if needed.

Comment: Will I be able to connect to billing service then without any developer account

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to fully test your implementation without the developer account.